# POI RuntimeException during creating WorkBook

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have a problem during creating Workbook. I have the following code for reading workbook:

```
wb = WorkbookFactory.create(file);
Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
```

It's pretty straightforward.
But during runtime, I've got the runtime exception:

> Exception in thread "Thread-7"
>   org.apache.poi.hssf.record.RecordFormatException: Unable to construct
>   record instance   at
>   org.apache.poi.hssf.record.RecordFactory$ReflectionConstructorRecordCreator.create(RecordFactory.java:101)
>     at
>   org.apache.poi.hssf.record.RecordFactory.createSingleRecord(RecordFactory.java:338)
>     at
>   org.apache.poi.hssf.record.RecordFactoryInputStream.readNextRecord(RecordFactoryInputStream.java:310)
>     at
>   org.apache.poi.hssf.record.RecordFactoryInputStream.nextRecord(RecordFactoryInputStream.java:276)
>     at
>   org.apache.poi.hssf.record.RecordFactory.createRecords(RecordFactory.java:480)
>     at
>   org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.(HSSFWorkbook.java:325)
>     at
>   org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.(HSSFWorkbook.java:288)
>     at
>   org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.(HSSFWorkbook.java:223)
>     at
>   org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.(HSSFWorkbook.java:381)
>     at
>   org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.(HSSFWorkbook.java:363)
>
> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Ran out of data reading
>   CellRangeAddress  at
>   org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddress.readUShortAndCheck(CellRangeAddress.java:78)
>     at
>   org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddress.(CellRangeAddress.java:72)
>     at org.apache.poi.hssf.record.FeatRecord.(FeatRecord.java:82)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
>     at
>   org.apache.poi.hssf.record.RecordFactory$ReflectionConstructorRecordCreator.create(RecordFactory.java:87)
>     ... 12 more

Probably I have an error in target xls file, but I'm not sure, because excel opens it without any problem. Does anyone knows what can be a reason of exception?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you check your file exist ? that the path match an existing file ? you could try creating it through `HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(filestream)` instead of `WorkbookFactory`

Comment: Also did you add all the libarys you need to your project. Might be "poi-3.XX.jar" and "poi-ooxml-3.XX" and the "ooxml-lib" folder.

Comment: POI usually fails on encounter of any cell with formula on it. Pls check.

Comment: From the exception I think maybe the issue is with the CellRangeAddress. Check whether its getting the data that your trying to put in the merged cell part.Just a guess though.Don't think the issue is with the getSheetAt() method

Comment: Thanks for replays. 1. File exists. 2. Yes, I have all of this libs in my classpath. 3. Document doesn't have any formulas in it. 4. Yes, it fails during check input stream against ENCODED_SIZE constant (it's value is 8), but I don't any idea why this happens

Comment: Can you share your pom and i believe you not using any SNAPSHOT version of library. Pls put full stack trace as well.

Comment: @Avis, Unfortunately, I have only this stack trace. Here is a pom: <br/>      <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.11</version>
        </dependency>

Comment: i believe your code is breaking on the 2nd line shared at the top but am not sure if you using HSSFWorkbook or XSSFWorkbook also if you are trying to create xls or xlsx sheet. Pls put initial code as well.

Comment: @Avis Code not even go to line 2. WorkBookFactory call HSSFWorkbook constructor inside factory method

Comment: If you open the problematic file in Excel, do a Save-As, then try with the resaved file, does that make the error go away?

Comment: Pls share your initial code where you declaring your file stream as well.

Comment: @Gagravarr, I tried, but it doesn't help